# Apache Solr: Faceted Search on multivalued fields

Tags: dictionary, solr, faceted-search, multivalue

Im currently working on a solr based search application.

I have two multivalued fields for example:
The data is read out of a database.

```
<int name="id">1</int>
<arr name="type">
<str>Marke</str>
<str>Modell</str>
<str>Fahrzeugtyp</str>
<str>engine</str>
</arr>
<arr name="value">
<str>Volkswagen</str>
<str>Golf</str>
<str>Golf TDI</str>
<str>V-Engine</str>
```

In my current solr configuration there is no relationship between these two multivalued fields. So that i can say "Marke = Volkswagen".

Besides there must be a relationship between Volkswagen and Golf. So I have to structure a taxonomy out of the two multivalued fields and of the values in the multivalued field itself.

I tried to build a typeAhead. In my current config when i search for Volkswagen - the possible suggestions contain audi and engine2 which does not refer to a Volkswagen model.
solr url:
http://xyz:8983/solr/suggest?&wt=json&facet=true&q=*&facet.field=value&facet.prefix=Volkswagen

I think [Solr Faceting on Multiple Concatenated Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521304/solr-faceting-on-multiple-concatenated-fields) has something to do with it, but I can't adjust it on my problem.

Thanks in reply

---

Maybe I can use the TemplateTransformer to combine value and type?

---

With TemplateTransformer I get a result: Marke | Volkswagen

In my data-import.xml (DIH)

```
<entity> name="tablename" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
<field column="test"  template="${tablename.TYPE} | tablename.VALUE}"/>
...
</entity>
```

---

Comment: Made some changes to formatting and corrected two grammar issues that may cause people to not understand your question.

Comment: really dont understand your question....please be bit more elaborate

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521304/solr-faceting-on-multiple-concatenated-fields help you?

Comment: i think you mean the same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336335/preserve-association-in-multivalued-in-solr ... have you found a solution? if so, please share  it with us

Comment: If you have found a solution to this, please can you share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been a long time since I've solved this problem. Try use this script in your data input handler. Attention - this script is based on solr 3.6.

```
 <script>
       <![CDATA[ function f1(row) 
         {
          var eldName = row.get('TYPE');
          row.put(eldName, row.get('VALUE'));
          return row;
         }
       ]]>
 </script>

 <entity name="e" transformer="script:f1" query="select TYPE, VALUE from X"></entity>
```

Comment: Added dynamic field and used the transformer. awesome!!