# preserve association in multivalued in solr

Tags: solr, multivalue

I have multivalued fields in my solr datasource. sample is

```
<doc>
<str name="id">23606</str>
<arr name="institution">
    <str>Harvard University</str>
    <str>Yale Universety</str>
    <str>Cornell University</str>
    <str>TUFTS University</str>
    <str>University of Arizona</str>
</arr>
<arr name="degree_level">
    <str>Bachelors</str>
    <str>Diploma</str>
    <str>Master</str>
    <str>Master</str>
    <str>PhD</str>
</arr>
</doc>
```

in the example above this user has got Bachelors degree from Harvard, Diploma from Yale, Master from Cornell, Master from TUFTS, and PhD from Arizona.
now if i search for users who have Bachelors degree and graduated from Harvard, i will get this user, which is correct.

`MyDomain:8888/solr/mycol/select?facet=true&q=:&fq=degree_level:Bachelors&fq=institution:Harvard+University`

**but if i want those who have Bachelors from Cornell, i will get this user as well, which is incorrect!**

`MyDomain:8888/solr/mycol/select?facet=true&q=:&fq=degree_level:Bachelors&fq=institution:Cornell+University`

**The question is: how could i preserve ordering/mapping in multivalued in solr?**
**Edit:**
By the way, i know that i can solve my problem by creating new field to contain concatenation of the degree with university (ie, "Bachelors_Harvard University", "Diploma_Yale Universety", and so on) but i need a solution based on solr core itself as i have a lot of multivalued fields with a lot of combinations.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue. Please share if you found something.

Comment: below you will find some suggestions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24953913/1008692 for possible answer. The script is based on solr 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a list of some suggestions

- try using dynamic fields
  **<dynamicField name="degree_level_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />** 
  and create fields dynamically while indexing degree_level_Bachelors with value Harward University and so on. so when you want to filter on Bachelors degree, filter on field degree_level_Bachelors. Similarly, if you want to allow filtering on institutions, create a dynamic field for institutions.
- you can pre define how you will be storing data: 
  <year><seperator><degree><seperator><institution><seperator><Major> etc etc.
  and then filter on the reqired regex.
  eg: 
  fq=educationDetails:2009@Bachelors@Harvard@* 
  this will give you all records with bachelors from Harvard in 2009. 
  you will have to come up with the regex expressions for all the different filters.
- two collections to correctly model the one-to-many relationship between user and degree queried using {!join}
- one collection at a "user-degree" level of granularity that gets deduped via Solr's field collapsing support.

Comment: My dynamic field does not seem to be working. I have added following in my data-config.xml file : `<field column="option_type_value" name="variant_option_type_value_${option_type}">`. But it done not work. How do I populate data in the dynamic field?

Comment: Ok. I used transformers and it worked. Thanks a lot for the help!!